# Can I miss attacks on purpose?

Tags: star-wars-force-and-destiny

So this may seem like a dumb question, but can I roll an attack and even if it hits miss on purpose to trigger say the feint skill assuming I had the advantages to do so?

Comment: Would aiming at a target (B) next to the "to-be-missed-target" (A), hitting the target (B) and thereby missing the other one (A) be an option? (I don't know the rules of your system.)

Answer (score 5):

**Yes...but**

Ultimately, a player's ability to retcon a declared action will fall within a GM's right to rule on permissibility.

Choosing to miss offers more opportunities for story to happen than simply hitting and doing damage. Some might have no problem with this. Others might have a problem with it for either procedural reasons, scene reasons, or both.

### Action Declaration in FFG Star Wars Roleplaying

One thing to recognize before ruling on whether this is appropriate is that the purpose of the roll is stated before being made.

If successful, the action being attempted occurs. If unsuccessful, it does not occur. These basic outcomes are then colored by Threats and Advantages, Despair and Triumph as appropriate. With this understanding of 1. declare intention 2. determine success of intention 3.  narrate outcome, it is inappropriate to change the outcome of the declared intention.

In other words, according to the method of play, it would be more appropriate to declare the intention to "*miss on purpose in order to set-up the opponent*" than it would be to see the results and to then switch from a declared attack to an intentional miss.

Obviously, if the player has made an erroneous declaration for some reason, or has realized something between making the declaration and resolving the action, being able to overrule the declared intention would be in the nature of good fun, and perhaps good story.

The GM's arbitration on this point should be in favor of that good story to be in keeping with the tone of the writing in this system.

**On Feint**

If the reason for this question is related primarily to the *Feint* Talent, it should be noted that it retroactively converts a 'miss' into a deceptive movement which allows the character to upgrade the opponent's next attack against them for either the normal *1 Triumph* cost, or the more-likely-to-get *3 Advantages* cost.

An upgraded difficulty on the opponent's attack is a nice effect to gain in a combat. This can be obtained without Feint by spending 1 Triumph, or by Spending 1 point from the Destiny Pool. In addition, Advantages can be spent 1 for 1 against the next active character to add Setback to their roll. Setback dice, statistically, have a stronger negative effect on the roll than upgrading does. Being able to apply an upgraded difficulty and apply Setback dice is an ideal situation.

**Ending fights with surrender or disabling**

With similar amounts of Advantages or Triumphs it is possible to end a combat without taking it through to maiming or death. See *Table 6-2 in Chapter 6: Combat and Conflict* for specifics on disabling opponents in the 3 Advantage or 1 Triumph row.

The scene itself might be playing out on more than one level. Elements of the emerging story in the combat may compel the opponent to surrender or grow overly cautious, leading to a cessation of the violence.

Comment: ok thank you should be fun with 2 ranks in feint, 2 in dodge, and 3 in force: sense

Comment: @Eric If this answer helped to solve your problem, or solved your problem, [accepting it](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) (clicking the check box) will indicate that.